# JS Report Server Console error: Authorization server has no "username" field in its response, token assumed as invalid

Tags: identityserver4, jsreport

My js report server with client ui applications was working with username filed by adding one claim e.g. Claim('username', 'user name value') in identityserver.
4 version 1.1. B ut recently client has upgraded the identityserver 4 version to 2.2.0 and netcoreapp2.1 .

Now the client ui applications get "Unauthorized" error. When I run the application locally I see one error in jsreport server console:
 error: Authorization server has no "username" field in its response, token assumed as invalid.

I have tried to find solution in the sample: 
https://github.com/bjrmatos/jsreport-with-authorization-server-sample but they have not upgraded the sample for latest .net core and identity server yet, I see the node js sample link "https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/NodeJsApi" does not exists. so I am unable to solve the issue. Can anyone help me please on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to solve this error by adding a claim type with user name and declare that in api resource scope:

```
         new ApiResource
            {
                Name="jsreportscope",
                DisplayName = "JavaScript based reporting platform",
                Scopes=
                {
                    new Scope()
                    {
                        Name="jsreportscope",
                        UserClaims = new List<string>(){"username" }
                    }
                },
                UserClaims = new List<string>(){"username"},
                ApiSecrets = { new Secret("yoursecret".Sha256()) },

            }
```

But now it goes to the previous problem that I fixed by adding a claim type matching the value of username field value with identity server 1.1 version but now we have upgraded the identity server version to 2.1 and again getting the error. The it was able to authorize any user of identity server for report access. Here is the **jsreport.config.js** code I am using:

```
{
   "store": { "provider": "fs" },
   "httpPort": 5004,
   "allowLocalFilesAccess": true,
   "extensions": {
    "authentication": {
       "cookieSession": {
       "secret": "<your strong secret>"
    },
    "admin": {
         "username": "IdentityServer4User@domain.com",
         "password": "Password"
    },
    "authorizationServer": {
       "tokenValidation": {
           "endpoint": "http://localhost:5000/connect/introspect",
           "usernameField": "username",
           "activeField": "active",
        "scope": {
           "valid": ["jsreportscope"]
        },
        "auth": {
           "type": "basic",
           "basic": {
               "clientId": "jsreport",
               "clientSecret": "yoursecret"
           }
        }
      }
    },
    "enabled": true
   },
   "authorization": {
     "enabled": true
   },
   "sample-template": {
      "createSamples": true
   }
 }
}
```

But now I can login and access reports from report server if login by only the user **IdentityServer4User@domain.com** any other users is getting unauthorized error. In the report server console the error is shown like:

```
error: username "OtherIdentityServer4User@domain.com" returned from authorization server is not a jsreport user.
```

I don not want to add all the identity server users to js report server.